# Haskell - Translating from syntactic sugar

Tags: haskell, syntactic-sugar

the task ist to translate this

```
f = do
    c <- [1 .. 200]
    b <- [1 .. 200]
    guard (c >= b)
    a <- [1 .. 200]
    guard (a >= b && (c^2 - a^2 == b^2))
    return (a,b, c)
```

into a non-sugar verion.

I think I got most of it figured out, but I'm stuck in the middle with a problem I need to fix before I can continue. So far I have:

```
f = [1 .. 200] >>= \c ->
    [1 .. 200] >>= \b ->
    if (c >= b) 
        then [1 .. 200] >>= \a -> if (a >= b && (c^2 - a^2 == b^2)) 
                                      then return(a,b,c)
                                      else return ()
        else return ()
```

which does not compile. When I put in (a,b,c) for the return, it compiles, but obviously it does not give the expected result anymore. How do I return "nothing" in the else branches?

If I put in ((),(),()) as the return values, the compiler gets a "No instance for (Num [a]) arising from the literal '1'"

Comment: By the way, `[1 .. 200]` could be considered "syntactic sugar" for `enumFromTo 1 200`.

Comment: There is more than one possible translation. For example, one could rewrite this as list comprehension and translate that one by a scheme that avoids concat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `return ()`, which is `[()]`, you must produce an empty list, so `else []` or, with the generic `guard` implementation `else mzero`.

The success branch produces a list of triples, `[(Int,Int,Int)]` (or `Integer`, or another `Num` type), so the failure branches must produce the same. Since failure means that no triple is found, they shall produce an empty list.

Note that in the `[]` monad, `return x` is just `[x]` and `mzero` (from `MonadPlus`) is the same as `fail whatever`, namely `[]`.

Comment: That was quick. And it fixed my problem. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: `guard` uses `mzero`, not `fail`.

Answer (score 5):

`guard` is not actually syntactic sugar. It's a function from `Control.Monad`.

```
guard :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()
guard True  = return ()
guard False = mzero
```

In case of lists `mzero` is `[]`. Read more here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/MonadPlus

Comment: I ran into problems placing the syntax correctly and decided to replace the guard command. It's now workng as it's supposed to be.
But the link is helpful for the follow-up task. Thanks. :)